# No censored data when doing tobit regression with censReg package in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to do basic tobit regression (left limit = 0, right limit = infinity) in R using censReg package.

I'm doing about 20 tobit regressions with different dependent variables.

Some tobit regressions works fine, but for some with no censored data, the process stops and an error is returned. The error message is as below

```
    Error in censReg(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 +  : 
    there are no censored observations
```

In this case, should I do OLS regression manually? Is there no way just to do tobit regression with no censored observations without returning an error?

Comment: When there is no censored data, what would you gain in using this method instead of a regular regression, for which the estimators will be  better?

Comment: I have to more than 80 regressions (differed by years and with different dependent variables). Some of them are censored and some of them are not. So it is very inconvenient to run Tobit first and see if there are no censored observations and change code for such dependent variables with no censored observations, and run again with normal OLS. I was wondering if there are any options to run OLS regression automatically if there are no censored observations.